# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException in Sitecore.Commerce.Engine

Tags: commerce-engine

I am trying to setup my Visual studio for Commerce Engine Custom Plug-in Development. I am getting the below error while trying to run Commerce Engine (Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 update 2).
[image]

> [00:05:31 INF] Connection id "0HLG7VMIJPCC6" bad request data:
>   "Invalid request line:
>   '\x16\x03\x03\x00\xAE\x01\x00\x00\xAA\x03\x03[}\x0B;\xFD\x14\xBF\xF9d\x91WG\xE0\xDF\xEF\xCEV\xAE!\x96#\x13\xCD!\xEDH\xCE5=\x9BnR\x00\x008\xC0,\xC0+\xC00\xC0/\x00\x9F\x00\x9E\xC0$\xC0#\xC0(\xC0'\xC0\x0A'"
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException:
>   Invalid request line:
>   '\x16\x03\x03\x00\xAE\x01\x00\x00\xAA\x03\x03[}\x0B;\xFD\x14\xBF\xF9d\x91WG\xE0\xDF\xEF\xCEV\xAE!\x96#\x13\xCD!\xEDH\xCE5=\x9BnR\x00\x008\xC0,\xC0+\xC00\xC0/\x00\x9F\x00\x9E\xC0$\xC0#\xC0(\xC0'\xC0\x0A'
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.RejectRequestLine(Byte*
>   requestLine, Int32 length)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.GetUnknownMethod(Byte*
>   data, Int32 length, Int32& methodLength)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler
>   handler, Byte* data, Int32 length)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler
>   handler, ReadableBuffer buffer, ReadCursor& consumed, ReadCursor&
>   examined)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.TakeStartLine(ReadableBuffer
>   buffer, ReadCursor& consumed, ReadCursor& examined)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.ParseRequest(ReadableBuffer
>   buffer, ReadCursor& consumed, ReadCursor& examined)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()

I have followed the same as in the blog to set it up.
https://medium.com/@siddharaju.s/debugging-sitecore-commerce-engine-custom-plugins-948a6b50e27f

Comment: Can you run on IIS Express and not on Commerce Engine (step 3 from blogpost) . I have same issue. Running on IIS Express for me is working fine.

Comment: Yes with the IIS express run fine but I am struggling with my custom plugin not showing up in the Commerce. This something as mentioned in https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2018/02/sitecore-experience-commerce-extending.html. As the plugin did not showed up I tried running the engine.

Comment: did you add reference from commerce engine to your plugin project?

Comment: I guess you mean reference of the plugin project to the Commerce Engine. Yes I did so and published the commerce engine to all the commerce sites(authoring,shops,minions,ops) and sitecore